# Add a row from the checkedlistbox to the DataGridView

Tags: c#

I want to add an item to the DataGridView 
If checked ListBox is checked. but add an item one time.Don't add it twice.

and I want the unchecked object in the checkedlistbox to be deleted as a row in the DataGridView. But my code is not working

[image: MY APP]

[Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vycv2g6icbzz3es/Untitled.mp4?dl=0)

```
private void checkedListBox3_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (int indexChecked in checkedListBox3.CheckedIndices)
    {
        if (checkedListBox3.GetItemCheckState(indexChecked) == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            dataGridView3.Rows.Add(checkedListBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
        else if (checkedListBox3.GetItemCheckState(indexChecked) == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {                    
            dataGridView3.Row[indexChecked].Delete;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is not working is very generic and it has several meanings. Please be specific. Are you getting an error? or is it not at all adding or removing based on your actions or is it adding/removing multiple time, etc.??

Comment: I don't get an error. but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each time the `checkedListBox` event is fired, you loop through all the checked items and add them to the DGV, hence the duplications.

Instead, you can do this:

```
private void checkedListBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{

    int selectedIndex = checkedListBox3.SelectedIndex;

    // If item is checked, add it to DGV
    if (checkedListBox3.GetItemCheckState(selectedIndex) == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        dataGridView3.Rows.Add(checkedListBox3.Items[selectedIndex].ToString());
    }

    // If item is unchecked, search for its first occurence in the DGV and remove it
    else if (checkedListBox3.GetItemCheckState(selectedIndex) == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView3.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .First(r => r.Cells["ENTER_YOUR_COLUMN_NAME_HERE"].Value.ToString().Equals(checkedListBox3.Items[selectedIndex].ToString()));

        dataGridView3.Rows.Remove(row);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi oumar, I try and gave the null error.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/02b02dle578f1gw/Untitled2.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Hi Yunus, I have tried to recreate the problem several times but the DGV and the checkedListBox seem to be working okay. Could you debug further and identify the root cause of this null reference (maybe expand the error details)? Is it the DGV or the list box item selected? Are you sure there are no leading/trailing spaces in the column names?

Comment: You should have edited your original answer with this, instead of posting another answer. May be you can remove the old answer provided below.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a [DerivedCollection](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/derived-lists). This would work like this:

You have a ReacvtiveList bound to your left panel with checkbox. Person class has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged of course and have Checked property.

Then you can do something like that:

`CheckedPeople = People.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x, x => x.Checked);`

This will create observable read-only collection storing exactly the same objects that your original list, but filtered by Checked property. Then you can bind CheckedPeople as ItemsSource to your grid and still edit them (only the collection is read only, since it's fed by changes in People collections).